# Using Select2 and Ajax on Devise/Registration controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a registration controller, with a user/edit page where user can update his/her profile upon registration. The user can choose among multiple dropdown menus. One of its drop down menu has more than 9000 choices, which I would like to call using AJAX instead of loading the entire table in a normal select2 approach.

I have a modified registration controller with the following :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected


  def edit
    @entreprises = Entreprise.all
    respond_to do|format|
      format.json{
        render :json => @entreprises
      }
    end
  end

...
```

In my users.edit.html I have a simple form with the line:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :company, :class =>"select2", :id => "ajax-example"%>
```

In javascript tag I have:

```
<SCRIPT>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ajax-example').select2({
            ajax: {
                url: "/edit.json",
                dataType: "json",
                results: function(data, page) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map( data, function(entreprise, i) {
                            return { id: entreprise.id, text: entreprise.company_name }
                        } )
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
<SCRIPT>
```

My routes are:

```
   devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations", confirmations: "confirmations", omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}, skip: :omniauth_callbacks
```

But when I reload the page it shows an empty select2 field. 
I am basing my work on the following example:

http://rails-select2-example.herokuapp.com/

Does anyone know what I am not doing well, what I should do to be able to populate the info from the Enterprise model to the registration page.

Thank you

Comment: Does it show error in logs? or in browser console?

Comment: Hey, no, not a single error.  It looks like it just does not trigger at all.

Comment: I thought it was a pretty common things and people would have already handled this issue. but it seems that nobody is responding.

Comment: Doesn't it shows in rails logs that request is being sent to server?

Comment: No no otherwise i could investigate and eventually figure out if the workflow is the right.